# Einstein Email Recommodations SFMC - price isn't updated correctly in displays

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Because the prices of our products can change every day, we update the price in the Einstein catalogue every day. This update comes through fine.

Only it looks like we need to re-publish the displays of the blocks to update the price? Is this a system limitation? Who has more knowledge of how this works?

Thanks,

Klaas

Comment: Are you sure that product catalog is updated before email is send?

Comment: Displays should update if you update the SalePrice via catalog import. The generation can be pretty slow, though, if you have a large catalog.

Comment: Are you updating the system field saleprice/regularprice. Or are you using a custom field like salepricedisplay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are updating your catalog through bulk update (ftp as opposed to streaming updates) The displays are are re-generated on a change to the following fields:

ProductName

ImageLink

OnlineAvailability

RegularPrice

SalePrice

If you are using streaming updates to update your catalog, a image refresh also occurs when any field used in the display is updated.

If you aren't updating one of the 5 fields above, ensure you do and the images will refresh for any item that has an update

Comment: Thanks for the input, one thing I forgot to mention. We use the content catalogue, the reason for this is that we already use the product catalogue for another type of products. 

We use the bulk to update the content catalogue, do you know which fields will trigger a regeneration for the content catalogue? We store the price in a custom field

Comment: It appears for content its Content Title, Availability and Content abstract